# Cooperative Multitasking system

Tags: multitasking

I'm trying to get around the concept of cooperative multitasking system and exactly how it works in a single threaded application.

My understanding is that this is a "form of multitasking in which multiple tasks execute by voluntarily ceding control to other tasks at programmer-defined points within each task."

So if you have a list of tasks and one task is executing, how do you determine to pass execution to another task? And when you give execution back to a previous task, how do resume from where you were previously?

I find this a bit confusing because I don't understand how this can be achieve without a multithreaded application.

Any advice would be very helpeful :)

Thanks

Comment: Single-threaded, bare metal (without an OS) cooperative multi-tasking is done all the time on embedded systems such as microcontrollers. Here is one interruptless example I wrote that uses time-stamps and state machines as a way to let multiple tasks do certain things when it is time and/or at fixed time intervals, all in a single main loop. https://stackoverflow.com/a/50032992/4561887

Answer (score 8):

In your specific scenario where a single process (or thread of execution) uses cooperative multitasking, you can use something like Windows' fibers or POSIX setcontext family of functions. I will use the term fiber here.

Basically when one fiber is finished executing a chunk of work and wants to voluntarily allow other fibers to run (hence the "cooperative" term), it either manually switches to the other fiber's context or more typically it performs some kind of yield() or scheduler() call that jumps into the scheduler's context, then the scheduler finds a new fiber to run and switches to that fiber's context.

What do we mean by context here? Basically the stack and registers. There is nothing magic about the stack, it's just a block of memory the stack pointer happens to point to. There is also nothing magic about the program counter, it just points to the next instruction to execute. Switching contexts simply saves the current registers somewhere, changes the stack pointer to a different chunk of memory, updates the program counter to a different stream of instructions, copies that context's saved registers into the CPU, then does a jump. Bam, you're now executing different instructions with a different stack. Often the context switch code is written in assembly that is invoked in a way that doesn't modify the current stack or it backs out the changes, in either case it leaves no traces on the stack or in registers so when code resumes execution it has no idea anything happened. (Again, the theme: we assume that method calls fiddle with registers, push arguments to the stack, move the stack pointer, etc but that is just the C calling convention. Nothing requires you to maintain a stack at all or to have any particular method call leave any traces of itself on the stack).

Since each stack is separate, you don't have some continuous chain of seemingly random method calls eventually overflowing the stack (which might be the result if you naively tried to implement this scheme using standard C methods that continuously called each other). You could implement this manually with a state machine where each fiber kept a state machine of where it was in its work, periodically returning to the calling dispatcher's method, but why bother when actual fiber/co-routine support is widely available?

Also remember that cooperative multitasking is orthogonal to processes, protected memory, address spaces, etc. Witness Mac OS 9 or Windows 3.x. They supported the idea of separate processes. But when you yielded, the context was changed to the OS context, allowing the OS scheduler to run, which then potentially selected another process to switch to. In theory you could have a full protected virtual memory OS that still used cooperative multitasking. In those systems, if a errant process never yielded, the OS scheduler never ran, so all other processes in the system were frozen. **

The next natural question is what makes something pre-emptive... The answer is that the OS schedules an interrupt timer with the CPU to stop the currently executing task and switch back to the OS scheduler's context regardless of whether the current task cares to release the CPU or not, thus "pre-empting" it.
If the OS uses CPU privilege levels, the (kernel configured) timer is not cancelable by lower level (user mode) code, though in theory if the OS didn't use such protections an errant task could mask off or cancel the interrupt timer and hijack the CPU. There are some other scenarios like IO calls where the scheduler can be invoked outside the timer, and the scheduler may decide no other process has higher priority and return control to the same process without a switch... And in reality most OSes don't do a real context switch here because that's expensive, the scheduler code runs inside the context of whatever process was executing, so it has to be very careful not to step on the stack, to save register states, etc.

** You might ask why not just fire a timer if yield isn't called within a certain period of time. The answer lies in multi-threaded synchronization. In a cooperative system, you don't have to bother taking locks, worry about re-entrance, etc because you only yield when things are in a known good state. If this mythical timer fires, you have now potentially corrupted the state of the program that was interrupted. If programs have to be written to handle this, congrats... You now have a half-assed pre-emptive multitasking system. Might as well just do it right! And if you are changing things anyway, may as well add threads, protected memory, etc. That's pretty much the history of the major OSes right there.

Answer (score 3):

The basic idea behind cooperative multitasking is trust - that each subtask will relinquish control, of its own accord, in a timely fashion, to avoid starving other tasks of processor time. This is why tasks in a cooperative multitasking system need to be tested extremely thoroughly, and in some cases certified for use.

I don't claim to be an expert, but I imagine cooperative tasks could be implemented as state machines, where passing control to the task would cause it to run for the absolute **minimal** amount of time it needs to make any kind of progress. For example, a file reader might read the next few bytes of a file, a parser might parse the next line of a document, or a sensor controller might take a single reading, before returning control back to a cooperative scheduler, which would check for task completion.

Each task would have to keep its internal state on the heap (at object level), rather than on the stack frame (at function level) like a conventional blocking function or thread.

And unlike conventional multitasking, which relies on a hardware timer to trigger a context switch, cooperative multitasking relies on the code to be written in such a way that each step of each long-running task is guaranteed to finish in an acceptably small amount of time.

Comment: In Windows 3.1 (a cooperative multi-tasking operating system), the Sleep API can be used to relinquish control to the operating system. With its help, it is possible that the application keep the data on the stack frame. Note that this doesn't work with the message queue processing model described in most text books, so the program needs to actively get messages from the message queue and process them if we want to write it this way (a loop of: Sleep-Process-Get message-Dispatch message). Otherwise the UI will freeze.

Answer (score 2):

The tasks will execute an explicit *wait* or *pause* or *yield* operation which makes the call to the dispatcher. There may be different operations for waiting on IO to complete or explicitly *yielding* in a heavy computation. In an application task's main loop, it could have a *wait_for_event* call instead of busy polling. This would suspend the task until it has input to process.

There may also be a time-out mechanism for catching runaway tasks, but it is not the primary means of switching (or else it wouldn't be *cooperative*).

Answer (score 2):

One way to think of cooperative multitasking is to split a task into steps (or states). Each task keeps track of the next step it needs to execute. When it's the task's turn, it executes only that one step and returns. That way, in the main loop of your program you are simply calling each task in order, and because each task only takes up a small amount of time to complete a single step, we end up with a system which allows all of the tasks to share cpu time (ie. cooperate).